# How can I set a breakpoint for when variable changes in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is there a way, using the eclipse debugger, to break any time a particular variable is written to?

The only thing I can think of is to manually set a breakpoint at every reference but my codebase is several million lines and I really don't want to do that.

Comment: Once you reach a breakpoint you can just step through, isn't that enough?

Comment: @Lucas step through several million of lines?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710013/1599699

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a watchpoint at the desired variable. Simply click on the line where the variable is declared, and select **Run -> Toggle Watchpoint**.

The watchpoint can break on either accessing the variable, modifying the variable, or both.

Comment: @ewok Is it a local variable or a field? I guess local variables are not supported by watchpoints.

Comment: Just removed that comment as `Toggle Breakpoint` only adds watchpoints on fields. Can't find a way to enable `Toggle Watchpoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**Expressions View** functionality from the Eclipse Debugger.](https://www.google.ro/search?q=eclipse%20expressions%20debug&oq=eclipse%20expressions%20debug&aqs=chrome..69i57.2841j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)